Why did Jordan Belfort see the plane crash as a sign from God?
While sailing to Monaco on his yacht, Jordan Belfort and his family
got stuck in a stormy sea. They were rescued by Italians and witnessed
the plane, which he had sent to come get them, being destroyed when a
seagull flew into the engine. He starts nararating this lines:

Jordan Belfort: Three people killed. You want a sign from God?
Well, after all this, I finally got the message.

Then scene cuts to the commercial highlights the struggle of achieving
financial independence while facing monthly bill payments.
Why did Jordan Belfort see the plane crash as a sign from God?

In the source novel, he doesn't seem to see it as anything more than the latest instance of terrible luck that he has been encountering

At the airport, we waited two hours for my private jet. Then a tiny man who worked at the private-jet terminal walked up to me and said, in heavily accented English: “Mr. Belforte, your plane crash. Seagull fly in engine, and plane go down in France. It will not come to get you.”
I was speechless. Did things like this happen to anyone else? I didn’t think so. When I informed the Duchess, she didn’t say a word. She just shook her head and walked away.

@Valorum If it's a novel, I would approach this community

The film is based on a novel. That is often a good place to look if you want to understand what the filmmakers were trying to get at
